# Python checking equality of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have a numpy array of source and destination ip's

```
consarray
array([['10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130'],
   ['104.244.42.130', '10.125.255.133']], dtype=object)
```

The actual array is much larger than this.

I want to create a set of unique connection pairs from the array:

In the given eg: it is clear that both rows of the numpy array are part of same connection (Just src and destination are interchanged, so it is outgoing and incoming respectively).

I tried creating a set of unique tuples.
like this:

```
conset = set(map(tuple,consarray))
conset
{('10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130'), ('104.244.42.130', '10.125.255.133')}
```

What i actually want is for ('10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130') and ('104.244.42.130', '10.125.255.133') to be considered the same so that only one of them will be in the set.

Can anyone tell me how do i go about doing this?

**EDIT:**

There have been some good answers, but actually i want another requirement,

I want that the first occurrence should always be the one retained irrespective of the ip address.

In the above example: ('10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130') appears first, so it is the outgoing connection, i want to retain this.

If the above example changed to:

```
consarray
array(['104.244.42.130', '10.125.255.133']],
    [['10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130'],dtype=object)
```

I would want ('104.244.42.130', '10.125.255.133') to be retained.

Comment: Does `set(frozenset(el) for el in consarray)` do what you want?

Comment: @JonClements Genius! Thanks. does it always ensure that the first one is kept and the second one is ignored?

Comment: I don't believe it will...

Comment: @VikashB order in set (or frozenset for that matter) is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JonClements An unlikely side effect of using a frozenset would be in the case where both ip addresses are identical (hopefully impossible) leaving you with a frozenset of just 1 element. Later on if you try to get the "two" members of the set it won't quite appear like you expect

Comment: @donkopotamus Well, it is a good thing that it is an impossible situation with regards to my data, but the ordering thing will cause me problems though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either apply *sorting* before making the *tuples*:

```
conset = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), consarray))
```

Or use *fronzensets* instead of *tuples*:

```
conset = set(map(frozenset, consarray))
```

To guarantee that the first item will be retained and the second not inserted, you could use a *regular* `for` loop:

```
conset = set()
for x in consarray:
    x = frozenset(x) 
    if x in conset:
        continue
    conset.add(x)
```

Comment: Ok, can you explain how the frozenset approach works, i looked into the docs and it is not clear, can you also specify which one will be dropped, is it the case that the first one will always be retained?

Comment: *frozensets* are *set* variants that are immutable and hashable. A set cannot be nested in another set, so you'll use a frozenset instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them first:

```
conset = set(map(tuple, map(sorted, consarray)))
print (conset)
```

gives:

```
{('10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `numpy`, you can use `numpy.unique`, eg:

```
a = np.array([('10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130'), ('104.244.42.130', ' 10.125.255.133')])
```

Then `np.unique(a)` gives you:

```
array(['10.125.255.133', '104.244.42.130'], dtype='<U14')
```

Comment: Well, i have edited the question, but this solution seems like it will guarantee that the tuple in which the smaller ip address is first will be retained, i actually want the first tuple to be retained regardless of the ip.